# SQL Query - is this Query safe to run for my Magento 2 store

Tags: magento2, database, product-images, sql, product-urls

I want to change all my downloadable product from **link_file** to **url_file**, so I created a query for that.
Can I get advice if this query is safe for me to run.

```
UPDATE downloadable_link SET link_url = CONCAT('http://www.mywebsite.info/download/',(substring_index(link_file, '/', -1)) ) , link_file =NULL , link_type = 'url' WHERE link_id >=0 AND link_id<=1000;
```

Thanks